# All path possible to score in a ball game

Tags: c, recursion

I have a H.W assignment in recursion in C that I have problem handling with:

> In a ball game you can either score 1 or 2 points each round, print all possible path for given end score of the game.

Example:

If the first team has end score 1 and second team has end score of 3 the possible scores are:

0:0 1:0 1:1 1:2 1:3

0:0 1:0 1:1 1:3

0:0 1:0 1:2 1:3

0:0 0:1 1:1 1:2 1:3

0:0 0:1 1:1 1:3

0:0 0:1 0:2 1:2 1:3

0:0 0:1 0:2 0:3 1:3

0:0 0:1 0:3 1:3

0:0 0:2 1:2 1:3

0:0 0:2 0:3 1:3

I tried to first get only the path using the 1 score option only, but none of the code I wrote worked:

```
goal_first(0, 0, first_team, second_team);

void goal_first(int first, int second,int max_first,int max_second)
{
    printf("%d:%d ", first, second);
    if (first != max_first)
    {
        goal_first(first + 1, second, max_first, max_second);
    }
    if (second != max_second)
    {
        goal_first(first, second + 1, max_first, max_second);
    }
    if (first==max_first && second==max_second)
    {
        printf("\n");
        printf("0:0 ");
    }   
}
```

I had to add the 0:0 part artificially,and that would print to many times at the end. It still does not do the job.

note: I can't use loops or static or global variables.

I am not asking for a solution, just would like help figuring out where to start.

Comment: "... but none of the code I wrote worked" ok, if you share the code, someone may be able to help

Comment: @4386427 I added what I did. thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll have postpone the printing until you have found a valid solution. To do that you'll have to "save the path" in some data structure (e.g. linked list) so that you can print all of the path when a solution is found.

Here is some **pseudo-code** that may help:

```
void pathFinderRec(uint scoreA, 
                   uint scoreB, 
                   uint targetA, 
                   uint targetB, 
                   list list_with_path_so_far)
{
    uint newScoreA = scoreA + last_list_element.scoreA;
    uint newScoreB = scoreB + last_list_element.scoreB;

    if (newScoreA == targetA && newScoreB == targetB)
    {
        // TODO: Print solution
        return;
    }

    if (newScoreA > targetA || newScoreB > targetB)
    {
        // No solution so just return
        return;
    }

    // TODO:
    add_new_element_to_end_of_list(newScoreA, newScoreB);

    // Here comes the recursion to cover all paths
    pathFinderRec(0, 1, targetA, targetB, list_with_path_so_far);
    pathFinderRec(0, 2, targetA, targetB, list_with_path_so_far);
    pathFinderRec(1, 0, targetA, targetB, list_with_path_so_far);
    pathFinderRec(2, 0, targetA, targetB, list_with_path_so_far);

   // TODO:
   remove_last_element_in_list();
}

void pathFinder(uint targetA, uint targetB)
{
    // TODO:
    initialize_empty_list();
    add_new_element_to_end_of_list(0, 0);  // Start with 0:0

    pathFinderRec(0, 1, targetA, targetB, list_with_path_so_far);
    pathFinderRec(0, 2, targetA, targetB, list_with_path_so_far);
    pathFinderRec(1, 0, targetA, targetB, list_with_path_so_far);
    pathFinderRec(2, 0, targetA, targetB, list_with_path_so_far);
}
```

and call it like:

```
pathFinder(1, 3);
```

Comment: Thanks. I can't use list either, but I believe I can create a string instead?

Comment: @segevp Or an array of a struct